# How to disable copy-as-image in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste, microsoft-office-2013

Recently it seems Excel has made copy-as-image default behaviour for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> hotkey (actually it seems to put the formatted text, table cell data, and a print-view image on the clipboard simultaneously).

This is bad if you have a workflow where you copy data from Excel and paste into another MS Office app, or into a web-form in Google Chrome, where the default behaviour of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is to paste the richest content available. In Atlassian products like Jira for instance this causes pasting to trigger insert of "screenshots" (image attachments).

So the question is:

**How can I tell Excel to NOT put image-data on the clipboard when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?**

*I am aware that it is possible to force pasting of plain text in the above mentioned apps. I am not asking how to do that. That is cumbersome because there is no standard way of doing it.*

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in Chrome.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>T</kbd> in Outlook.

etc...

Answer (score 1):

*You can try this VBA code to check whether Clipboard has Image Data or not, and if it has, then this code will prevent to paste it.*

**Remember, the effect of Ctrl+C can be stopped only by disable it. So I do believe that this is the best possible solution.**

Note, before you execute this VBA code, in VB Editor click **Tool** then **References** and select **Microsoft Form 2.0 Object Library**.

Better you use the code with Workbook open event.

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()

   Dim BufObj As MSForms.DataObject
   Set BufObj = New MSForms.DataObject

   BufObj.GetFromClipboard

   On Error Resume Next
   ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

    If Err Then
       MsgBox "Nothing in ClipBoard!": Err.Clear

    Else

      MsgBox "Picture in ClipBoard": Err.Clear
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   End If

End Sub
```

**NB:** You also need to create one **Command Button Click event** to activate the *Cut Copy Mode*. This simple code will do it.

```
Application.CutCopyMode = True

Application.DisplayAlerts = Ture
```

*This code was tested by me, before I've posted it here.*

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that what you are copying doesn't include an object that excel recognizes as an image, such as a macro button.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).